# jquery not worked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jquery:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    alert("true")
    var $d_id = $(this).attr("name").substring(2)
    var $d_link = 'd_' + $d_id

    $("#"+$d_link).html('<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="d_event_'+
        $d_id + '" name="d_' + $d_link + '" > <img src="/images/r.png" alt="r"></a>');
});
```

and html:

```
<div id=d_1></div>
```

when I click the first time on the show messages (true) and inserted a picture, but when I click again the message is not displayed. Why can not I see the message after the first click?

Comment: End your lines with semi colon ;

Comment: what is `disput_link`?

Comment: are u using a for loop for this in html?

Comment: `.click` only works on elements that are in the DOM when the document is loaded.  you have to use jquerys `.on` method for elements that are inserted with js

Comment: Arun P Johny it's a typo

Comment: If you paste the correct html then people here are quite able to solve this issue. Current one is quite hard to get which `a` you are clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector, as-is, will not bind to elements created after the DOM is ready. You need to bind to a static parent using `.on()`.

Using the simplest example:

```
$("body").on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    alert("true");
    var $d_id = $(this).attr("name").substring(2);
    var $d_link = 'd_' + $d_id;

    $("#"+$d_link).html('<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="d_event_'+
        $d_id + '" name="' + $d_link + '" > <img src="/images/r.png" alt="r"></a>');
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work, I do not see any message even after the first click.

Answer (score 0):

use `on` delegate events...

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(event) {
     alert("true")
     var $d_id = $(this).attr("name").substring(2);
     var $d_link = 'd_' + $d_id;

     $("#"+$d_link).html('<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="d_event_'+
    $d_id + '" name="' + $d_link + '" > <img src="/images/r.png" alt="r"></a>');
});
```

read more [here](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) about `on` direct and delegated events..

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work, I do not see any message even after the first click.

Comment: it should ..i added the `;` that was missing...what error are u getting ..let me know..

Comment: i remove extra code, $(document).on("click","a",function(event) {alert("true")}); but it does not work...

Comment: your are missing `""` in your provided html `<div id="d_1"></div>` can u please provide the full html .. the `<a>` part where the click event is atttached

Comment: <div id="d_1"><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="d_event_1" name="d_1" > <img src="/images/r.png" alt="r"></a></div>

Comment: I found the solution, i replase part of html (only img) and it work, but I interest in solution to my original problem

Comment: your code looks fine....you can delegate to  `$('#d_1').on("click","a",function(event) {`.. can u create a fiddle ??